# AngularJs, Controller is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I am using node js with mongodb and express js and angular as front-end to make a web application.The problem is that I added a new controller to handle the login but seems that whatever I do I get the same error:
**Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'userlogint' is not registered.** 
I actually did a few research and I was searching for answers but nothing that would help me cause same code works for the other 2 controllers and I really have no ideea why this one would not work.Below I will paste my code:
Here is my app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    controller:'controllertipproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/Default.html'
})
.when('/produse',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/Produse.html'
})
.when('/login',{
    controller:'userlogint',
    templateUrl: 'views/Login.html'
})
.when('/produse/:tipp',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/CategorieProduse.html'
})
.when('/produse/detalii/:id',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/DetaliiProduse.html'
})
.when('/produsee/adaugareprodus',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/AdaugareProdus.html'
})
.when('/produse/editprodus/:id',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/EditareProduse.html'
})
.when('/despre',{
    controller:'controllerproduse',
    templateUrl: 'views/About.html'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
});

});
```

And here is my controller file userlogint.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('userlogint', 
['$scope','$http','$location','routeParams',function
($scope,$http,$location,$routeParams){
$scope.Loginto = function(
$http.post('/api/login/',$scope.userr).then(succesCallback,errorCallback);
function succesCallback(response){
    $scope.loginn = response.data;
    window.location.href = '#/'
}
function errorCallback(error){
    throw error;
}
)
}]);
```

The error triggers when I am on the page **http://localhost:3000/login**
I mention that the other 2 controllers have the same specific code like this one and they work.

Comment: Import the `userlogint` file into your `index.html` file. Is not registered means you did not import file to project

Comment: Yes I forgot to did that , this is my first project and it was a gap of like 2 weeks between date when I start project and the date I continued to work on it.Thank you very much.

Comment: Good luck man ;)